# Excel VBA Dictionary of Collections

Tags: vba, excel

I want to have a dictionary where the key will be a string providerName and the value will be a collection of categoryId's. However, this is the result I am getting:

[image]

It looks like the key is just item1, item2, item3 etc and the value is just the providerName, and the collection of categoryIds is not there at all.

My code:

```
For i = 2 To Selection.Rows.Count
providerName = SingleLine(i, 1)
categoryId = SingleLine(i, 3)
Dim categoryIdCollection As New Collection
If Not providerNamesDictionary.exists(providerName) Then
    categoryIdCollection.add (categoryId)
    providerNamesDictionary.add key:=providerName, Item:=categoryIdCollection
Else
    Dim tempCategoryIdCollection As Collection
    Set tempCategoryIdCollection = providerNamesDictionary(providerName)
    tempCategoryIdCollection.add (categoryId)
    Set providerNamesDictionary(providerName) = tempCategoryIdCollection
End If
```

How do I get the key to be the providerName and the value to be a collection of categoryIds?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Two issues here:

1. `Dim` inside a loop does not work as you expect.  It creates a variable the first time it's encountered, thereafter it's ignored. Net affect, you only ever create one Collection and add all catagoryID's to it
   To fix item 1, put `Dim categoryIdCollection As Collection`  outside the loop and `Set categoryIdCollection = New Collection` inside the loop (instead of `Dim ...`)
2. The Watch window on a dictionary shows the keys, not items.  To see the Items (ie the `Collections`) , watch `providerNamesDictionary.items`